# Acer Spin111-31 battery is not recognized

Tags: battery

I have an Acer Spin111-31 C2W3 PC. Running Windows 10.

I recently took the back panel off to reset my BIOS password. After I put everything back together the computer is not using the battery correctly. It shows at 100% charge, however as soon as I unplug my power source the laptop dies. I have gone back three times to make sure all the connections are properly in place, and they have been since the first book. Is there something I'm missing? Is there a process to initializing the battery after it has been disconnected?

I just downloaded [BatteryInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) battery health check tool.

And it is giving me the following information:

```
Battery Name: ACK14B8K
Manufacture Name: LGC
Serial Number: 55752
Power State: Discharging, AC Power
Current Capacity (in %): 100.0%
Current Capacity Value: 42,758 mWh
Full Charged Capacity: 42,758 mWh
Designed Capacity: 48,944 mWh
Battery Health: 87.4
Voltage: 16,798 millivolts
Charge/Discharge Rate: 0 milliwatts
Chemistry: Lithium Ion
Low Battery Capacity (1): 2,341 mWh
Low Battery Capacity (2): 2,979 mWh
Number of charge/discharge cycles: 0
```

The information matches what's written on my battery so it seems as if it is detected and full, but the laptop won't draw power from it.

---

I realized when I put a little pressure on a certain part of my case the battery was functional, so I put all the screws back in and it seems to be working. Except for one thing. When it is plugged in it says Fully Charged, but as soon as I unplug it it reads 98%, and it doesn't show discharging if I leave it sitting unplugged for a while. However it is running off of the battery now. I can live with that, but wondering if that could be an easy fix?

Comment: Unfortunately, the information from the application in question, only confirms it's able to communicate with the battery.  That does not mean the cable and/or connector that is connected to the battery is fully functional.

Comment: So I realized when I put a little pressure on a certain part of my case the battery was functional. So I put all the screws back in and it seems to be working. Except for one thing. When it is plugged in it says Fully Charged, but as soon as I unplug it it reads 98%, and it doesn't show discharging if I leave it sitting unplugged for awhile. However it is running off of the battery now. I can live with that, but wondering if that could be an easy fix?